# How to change material input text style react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material ui `TextField`
I want to change style of the part that I mentioned in text field (see image)

or

font of the text that user writes

[image]

I've tried to use material API but it shows same result

```
 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      "&. input":{
        fontFamily:'roboto'
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: You want to change font style?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you mean with "this part", but unrelated to that `&.` is not a valid selector

Comment: @MaulikSakhida yes i want to chanege font style

Comment: @hotpink i meant the part that i mentioned at the image, style of text that user writes

Comment: Are you using Material UI `TextField` component or html `input` tag ?

Comment: I'm using material ui text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MUI TextField try this

```
<TextField inputProps={{ style: { 'fontFamily' : 'roboto'} }} id="standard-basic" label="Standard" />
```

OR

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {  fontFamily: 'roboto' }
    }));

<TextField classes={{ input: classes.root }} id="standard-basic" label="Standard" />
```

Either one of these should work.